# display rendered values on the same line

Tags: apex, visualforce, rendered, table

I made a < apex:reapeat> tag within a table and I want to use rendered to display or not values from a list, base on an input search.

The problem is if I have 5 values in the list for example:

example 1

example 2

example 3

example 4

example 5

And I enter 5 to the search input - I will get 4 empty rows and my value will be display still in its 5th place :

""

""

""

""

example 5

Its happening with PageBlockTable also.

any Idea?

my code :

```
 **"ProdName" - having the value of the text input**

<table class="table">
              <apex:repeat value="{!productoList}" var="plist" >
        <tr>

          <td>
             <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! AND(act!=null,contains(plist.label,prodName))}">
             <apex:commandLink value="{!plist.label}" action="{!checkTheValues}">

               <apex:param value="{!plist.value}"  name="productSelected" />
               <apex:param value="{!plist.label}"  name="productSelectedLabel" />

                  </apex:commandLink>

                </apex:outputPanel> 

            </td>




       </tr>

    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, you want to display all the 4 rows with blank as well as the value in the fifth row?

Comment: when I click on the search input all the list is shown, one under other like it should be.
But when I use the "filter" by pressing on a letter, Like in the example - "5" I want only "example 5" will be shown but in the first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your `tr`'s are rendering although the components within it are not rendered. To fix this, you will have to hide the `tr`'s as well.

You can do it using style attribute of `tr` i.e. conditionally display the `tr`'s using below code

```
<tr style="{!IF(AND(act!=null,contains(plist.label,prodName)), '','display:none')}">
```

so, your visualforce page will be

```
<table class="table">
      <apex:repeat value="{!productoList}" var="plist" >
        <tr style="{!IF(AND(act!=null,contains(plist.label,prodName)), '','display:none')}">
            <td>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! AND(act!=null,contains(plist.label,prodName))}">
                    <apex:commandLink value="{!plist.label}" action="{!checkTheValues}">
                        <apex:param value="{!plist.value}"  name="productSelected" />
                        <apex:param value="{!plist.label}"  name="productSelectedLabel" />
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:outputPanel> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

Comment: GREAT! Thanks!  - just fixed the tr style  - plist with plist.label and it works!
Thank you!

Comment: Great ! Updated that part in the answer